# Can I clone a branch of an unrelated remote repo into a branch of my git repo, and keep it updated?

Tags: git

I have a local repo with some code in it in different branches. There happens to exist a git repo out in the world that has the same software, but a disconnected git history. (I don't think it matters, but I know for sure that that repo uses a different branch naming scheme than mine, so there are no conflicts.)

I want to clone a specific branch of that remote repo into a new, matching branch of my local repo, and subsequently be able to update it with `git pull`.

Is this possible, and if so... how?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a local repository can track any number of upstream repositories:

```
git remote add upstream2 https://...
```

and clone branches from those repos:

```
git checkout -b upstream2-main upstream2/main
```

That branch will be pullable as usual, from its original repository; the only restriction is that you won’t be able to merge branches directly between disconnected histories. Cherry-picking and other such operations will work, as long as the files being modified are present in the target of course (but you can always fix things up afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the upstream for your local repo.

```
git pull --set-upstream https://path/to/repo/repo.git
```